# Prevent checkbox from triggering an onclick collapse event

Tags: angular, angular-material2

So I have multiple cards in my application and each card has a header component that, once clicked, collapses the card so you only see the header. The problem I am having is that some headers contain checkboxes and clicking the checkboxed trigger the click event for the header. Any suggestions on preventing this from happening?

```
<md-card>
   <md-card-content>
      <md-toolbar (click)="toggleSection()">
         <span>{{section.Name}}</span>
         <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="section.isChecked">(Check to include section)</md-checkbox>
      </md-toolbar>
   </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Comment: You need to clarify a little, do you mean it triggers when you click on the check box? Put the check box in a separate div/span.

Comment: yes. when you click the checkbox, the section collapses, which I don't want to happen. The checkbox is its own entity. Wrapping the checkbox in a div didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your toolbar `<md-toolbar>` is wrapping around the checkbox, when you click on checkbox you actually clicking on the `<md-toolbar`>. You can do a few things put the check box in a separate div/span, give it a higher z-index, use `event.preventDefault();` in your  `toggleSection()` function.